# Efficiency of asynchronous non-blocking server socket

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, asynchronous, epoll

I want to write a server program which accepts incoming connections and process received requests. The first idea appeared in my head was to use non-blocking socket with `epoll()` or `select()`.

For instance, when `epoll()` returns, it gives me a socket array with available IO events. Then I have to loop over the socket array to send and receive data, once the buffer is entirely received or sent, a callback functions is executed. This is also the technique the most discussed on internet.

However, if I use this technique, my program will keep all the other sockets waiting while it is dealing with one client connection. *Isn't it an inefficient way to go if the request of client is time-consuming?*

In the documents that I've found they said that such one thread/process design can easily handle hundreds of connections simultaneously, and multithread design is always heavily criticized for its complexity, system overhead etc.

Thus, my question is: *How to design an efficient server program if it has to handle heavy workload?*

Thanks.

Comment: @SergeyA I didn't reallize that it was such a broad topic. But I think I've already got my answer, and an good article to read. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Million dollar questions with a million different trade offs. For those that get Monty Python...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pWS8Mg-JWSg

Back to reality... Apache2 can handle heavy workloads, nginx can handle heavy workloads, so can Node, Tomcat, Jetty, JBoss, Netty... In fact any of the well knowns applications servers in use today and quite a few less well known ones can handle heavy workloads and they all use various combinations of threads, events and processes to do it. Some languages ie Erlang or Go etc allow you to easily spin up high performance application servers in a few hundred lines of code.

Although out of date now the following page has some great information on why this is not a simple problem...

```
http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html
```

Rather than worrying about performance now get something working, benchmark it then ask how to make it faster... if you've been smart and made sure that you have a modular design swapping out parts of it will be relatively easy ie look at what Apache did with MPM, a pluggable engine with completely different performance characteristics etc.

Once you have your server outperforming any of the above in benchmarks your answer to this question would likely be accepted.

Comment: Thank you for the reference.

Answer (score 1):

Heavy workload is a misleading term and in the end, it doesn't really dictate how you should design your system. The main issue here, is one of responsiveness and its requirements. If processing a single request takes a long time, and you do not want to starve the other clients (which you probably don't), then a single thread design will obviously not do. You should at least have a thread (or one per client) that handles responding to the request in some manner, even if only to notify the client that the request is being processed.